# Trying to store file/folder names from dirent struct to linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, opendir

```
typedef struct s_files
{
    char *name;
    struct s_files *next;
} t_files;

t_files *add_files()
{
    DIR *pDir;
    struct dirent *pDirent;

    t_files *head = (t_files *)malloc(sizeof(t_files));
    t_files *cur = head;

    pDir = opendir(".");
    while((pDirent = readdir(pDir)))
    {
        if(cur == NULL)
            cur = (t_files *)malloc(sizeof(t_files));
        cur->name = pDirent->d_name;
        cur->next = NULL;
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    closedir(pDir);
    return (head);
}



void print_files(t_files *head)
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
        printf( "%s ", head->name);
}
```

I am trying to store filenames from dirent struct to linked list. But when I tried to print all, only first one gets outputted.

Output should be similar to "ls -a"

Comment: The buffer, including the filename, returned from readdir by-address can/will be overwritten with each subsequent call. As you're only storing a *pointer* to the filename, you're storing a pointer to the memory that is constantly being re-written with each file. If you want to keep the name you have to make a deep copy in to a buffer you manage yourself. That said, you're also leaking a ton of memory, as you're not forward chaining your linked list properly.

Comment: Also: you assign `cur` here: `cur = (t_files *)malloc(sizeof(t_files));` and 3 lines below you throw it away, putting NULL into `cur`. Look closely at that code and explain it.

Comment: help others help you. help others help others. Post a complete code, something one can compile.

Comment: note that a linked list is a list of nodes, linked nodes. Your code has only something like a node. There is no list. A better model makes life easier and leads to reusable and more maintainable code.

Comment: @arfneto While it can make the design easier, it's not necessary to have separate list and node types, the list can be represented using a pointer to the first node. Consider that Lisp, the archetype of list processing, only has nodes (conses).

Comment: Sure it is not necessary, @Barmar, but it will lead to _metadata_ spread around the code, like pointers for list head and tail and for keeping count of _size_ . Consider metadata inside `C++` or _java_ or _python_  list: no one keeps an external value for `size`. We can make life harder for sure. For beginners it is an invitation to fail. Just look at `head` in the code above, and at the loop with no size information. Encapsulation is a powerful thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```c
t_files *add_files()
{
    DIR *pDir;
    struct dirent *pDirent;

    t_files *head;
    t_files *cur = NULL;

    pDir = opendir(".");
    while((pDirent = readdir(pDir)))
    {
        if (cur == NULL)
        {
            cur = (t_files *)malloc(sizeof(t_files));
            head = cur;
        }
        else
        {
            cur->next = (t_files *)malloc(sizeof(t_files));
            cur = cur->next;
        }
        cur->name = strdup(pDirent->d_name);
    }
    cur->next = NULL;

    closedir(pDir);
    return (head);
}
```

- First you have directly overwritten the first node, resulting in a memory leak.
- Then you have incremented cur to the next node, but then you loose your pointer to the last node, so you haven't assigned the next node to your last node. This results in a memory leak and also you aren't saving any information besides the first node.
- I think you don't own `pDirent`, so you should take a copy of the name. Make sure to `free` it.

Note, that this code, like yours, doesn't check for `malloc` or `strdup` returning `NULL`, which you should always do.

See: [Should I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/should-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) for why you maybe shouldn't cast the result of `malloc`.

Also always consider enclosing an if into a block. There have been serious bugs due to this.

Comment: This solved my problem thank you! According readdir man page, dirent struct may be statically allocated and should not be free'd.